# How to properly force MKMapView to redraw the MKOverlayRenderer with the same zoom scale

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

MKMapView is drawing MKOverlayRenderer by tiles. The problem is that not all tiles of the overlay are drawn on the screen with the same zoom scale. At the same time the map behind the overlay is drawn precisely and correctly. The renderer was forced to redraw using

```
[renderer setNeedsDisplay];
```

each time I resize the overlay, so that all levels of cached overlay tiles must be invalidated, and the proper tile level must be drawn.

The actual result is that when I'm resizing the overlay, some part of it becomes 2~3~5 times zoomed. It looks ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem very similar to this, which turned out to be caused by returning a `boundingMapRect` that wasn't large enough to cover the whole overlay.  MapKit would still call my drawing routine, but sometimes my overlay wouldn't display and sometimes it would come out at the wrong zoom scale.

Solution was to supply a `boundingMapRect` that was large enough.